# Angular number input auto increments when using orderBy filter and updateOn Blur

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a view that uses angular, and I noticed that a number input in an `ng-repeat` will automatically increment if a certain sequence of actions is performed.

This happens when the following are true:

- Using Angular 1.3 and up (not tested on angular 2)
- `ng-repeat` uses `orderBy`
- number input uses `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`

***Update: These spinner controls are part of webkit and only appear in webkit browsers such as Chrome. IE and Edge are not webkit browsers and will not display the spinner controls.***

If I use angular 1.2, or I remove either the `orderBy` or the `updateOn: 'blur'` the problem does not show.

I understand that I can fix it by removing either of these features, but I do not exactly understand why this is happening.

**Can anyone explain why the number input auto increments?**

See the example below for steps to reproduce the issue.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    'Name': 'Item1',
    'Seq': 0
  }, {
    'Name': 'Item2',
    'Seq': 0
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-info">Steps to reproduce:
  <ol>
    <li>Hover over the sequence input for item 1 and press the up arrow once</li>
    <li>Hover over the sequence input for item 2 and press the up arrow once</li>
    <li>The sequence number will now continuously increment</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 50px;">Seq#</th>
      <th style="width: 50px;">Seq</th>
      <th>Item #</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : 'Seq'">
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" style="width: 100px;" ng-model="item.Seq" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
      </td>
      <td>{{item.Seq}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would fix this, but this is definitely a quirk with how the HTML number spinner operates.  when you increment the first spinner, the `orderBy` doesn't trigger immediately, because the input box hasn't lost focus.  When you `mousedown` the second spinner, it instantly triggers the focus change, which triggers the `orderBy`, which causes the input box to shift to the opposite location before the `mouseup` is handled, causing the spinner to act like you are holding the mouse down.

Comment: For me the sequence number does not increment, the table though re-orders when I focus out of the first cell, as expected. Therefore if you click on the second cell's "up" arrow you will get number 2

Comment: @jimmious, what browser are you using? I just tested in edge and IE, and i do not see the up/down buttons, so the issue cannot be reproduced in those. I'll update the question to show that the issue is currently in chrome for me.

Comment: Chrome and I just got your error. I think the difference was that I was clicking in the field before clicking the up arrow. That is...interesting.

Comment: I believe I understand it now, and it may be working as designed.
Because the up/down arrows can be held to increment, they use the mousedown/mouseup events instead of click. Because of 'blur', the model doesnt update until focus is lost, at which time the sorting occurs. So when you click the up arrow on the second input, it registers a mousedown event, then the first input model updates, the ng-repeat applies the orderBy, and now the control is no longer under the mouse, so it never registers the mouseup event.

Comment: actually it looks like 'onBlur', 'onMouseOut', or 'onMouseUp' would cancel the button press, but none of those happen, when the rows re-sort and the input retains focus

Comment: I think the core of the issue is that `orderBy` redraws the DOM, which confuses the spinner.